# How to use an SSD to cache entire Linux distro installed on HDD?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, cache

Title pretty much sums it up. I’d like to install Ubuntu Server to an HDD and use an SSD as cache for the entire operating system.

I know this isn’t the most recommended and it is a better idea to use SSD as boot drive and HDD for storage but that is my current configuration and I would like to try it the other way for reasons.

Comment: Sorry, but I voted to close as there is no question posed, and while you may have an idea of what you are askinf, we dont. (and off the top of my head I can think of no less then 4 answers to what I thunk your question may mean)

Comment: You may want to clarify why you need an HDD if you have an SSD bug enough to fir the whole distro?  Are you looking to have evertthing on the HDD but hace a cache for thr root fs?  What is your memory profile - and have you considered the impact of memory cachinf?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Is this being done in a VM or bare metal?  What are the relative sizes of the ssd,hdd and ram?

Comment: How familiar are you with ZFS? BTRFS? LVM?  Tuning swap?

Comment: I need HDD even though the SSD is 120G because the computer is a file server and not a desktop. Rather than manually choosing what goes on which drive, I’d like the OS to automatically do it for me based on what files are accessed more frequently. I also want both drives to show up as the same block device for simplicity. I want efi and cache on SSD while root and home go on HDD but are cached by SSD. Current memory is 16G 2400mhz but the motherboard only supports up to 1333, I’ll be upgrading to 32G by Christmas. Problem I’m trying to solve is that I want my SSD to cache everything on HDD.

Comment: It’s being done on a physical machine, ssd is 120G and hdd is 5T

Comment: Had lots of luck with this guide but I created /boot on HDD without thinking about it so I’m about to start over and put boot on the right drive. 

https://kloppenborg.net/blog/installing-ubuntu-20-04-with-bcache/

Comment: Edit your question, please, to give us a good question showing your research, your intent, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try provide some thoughts/suggestions to answer your questions below.  That said, I think you are likely making a mistake (indeed this seems to me to be almost an XY problem - assuming a solution and asking how its done, rather then ask how to solve the problem.)

Specifically, I don't believe you have taken into account the following, which make a massive difference -

- SSDs - especially smaller/older ones (as implied by the 120 gig size) tend to slow down over time - often so they are slower then HDD's after a few years.  Some of this is down to older firmware/trim.
- The OS caches commonly read content in memory automatically, so tuning you swap file and vm.swappiness can get a significant percentage of the way there without the overhead.   If you have 16 gigs of memory for a fileserver you are well on / past the way of diminishing returns - especially for  reads.
- A minimal OS install is small and there are significant advantages to separating out root and data volumes in a file server.  Having a 10 gig partition for the OS should be no big deal.  You can even put it on the HDD and, with a low value for vm.swappiness, after the system has booted it will only cache the stuff thats needed.
- You have not mentioned RAID/backups at all.  As an expert, that is pretty scary to me.   Most NAS's would have some kind of RAID, because HDD's are the most likely thing to fail in a computer, and SSD's are also known to fail suddenly and catastrophically.

**Some thoughts/answers**

Based on the additional information you have provided - ie that his is for a file server, I put to you you want to look at either using LVM or ZFS.

I'll cover off LVM briefly because I think ZFS is likely a better fit here.  LVM allows you to abstract your disk (including the partition containing your root filesystem).  It fits in with conventional disk/filesystem paradigms provides powerful flexibility for things like snapshots, resizing and managing disks, redundancy and handling multiple disks.  Importantly for you, it also provides for using fast disk as cache - for example https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html

That said, if you are coming to this "new", you may be better off with ZFS. Loosely speaking, ZFS is a "new" paradigm in filesystems, somewhat merging disks/partitions with a filesystem, and it has extremely powerful features - snapshotting for example is more powerful and efficient then LVM, you can do things like snapshotting, resilvering, deduplication etc - and importantly here, it has very powerful caching.   The disadvantages are the learning curve (but if you have not used LVM, its probably no harder), it wants more memory then LVM - but at 16 gigs you have way more then you need.  You will see arguments online about using ECC memory - this is because ZFS cares more about data integrity then other solutions - but as you are using an older computer and single HDD and ancient SSD, I'm guessing you don't care **that** much about reliability, so you can ignore these arguments - ZFS is still a powerful solution here.   See https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html for ZFS on root on Ubuntu.

I comment that ZFS is very often used as the backend of NAS's - its made for this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you have references about *"SSDs - especially smaller/older ones (as implied by the 120 gig size) tend to slow down over time - often so they are slower then HDD's after a few years. Some of this is down to older firmware/trim."* ?

Comment: I see little providing them as them unless I know what type model SSD - but here is a starting point - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification - also look at the tbw figures - the smaller the drive the smaller the tbw - and factor in that caching is quite heavy on writes - http://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html seems to canvas the issues in depth.  (Oh, and experience plays a part as well)

Comment: You are refering to write amplification and endurance, not to "slowdown over the years". Indeed the write performances can drop after a while (but it can be hours, not necessarily years) if 1) the drive is near full and/or 2) the usage consists of heavy write workloads. Both conditions are indeed true if the SSD is used as a cache, but this is not true in the general case. And such use case can be mitigated by a larger overprovisioning (a 120GB drive has actually 14% overprovisioning, which is already a good amount). In all cases the read performances are not significantly altered.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware your last comment came across as combative (and only partially correct).  Out of curiosity - What model is your SSD?

Comment: It's not my intention to be combative or aggressive, I am just making my case. Maybe you have a different perception because english is not my native language. The SSD model doesn't matter too much, they all behave similarly (yes with different performances and endurances). Also, some Synology NAS models offer the possibility to have SSDs that are used as cache, so it doesn't look a too bad idea.

Comment: @PierU,  The thing is that the make and model of the SSD absolutely can make a difference in your application - problems with write amplification are likely to be MUCH worse on older drives before it was a solved problem (and many/most 120gig drives would very much be older drives).   Using an SSD as a cache is not bad "per-se" - indeed I do that on my NAS and the functionality is built into ZFS - its just that 120 gig drives - because of their size and age - are likely not a great fit for this application....

Comment: I clearly recall the first time I discovered that SSD drives could be slow - it was a 120 gig Intel drive, used in an office enviromnent (mainly web, email and some office - nothing heavy), and after about 2 years it was giving throughput half that of an HDD.  I've not seen that on newer drives.

Comment: (just in case: I am not the OP)